# Image URL instes of base64 in GrapesJS

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

Is there any option to insert image URLs into HTML instead of base64 images while creating HTML templates in GrapesJS? Below is a sample HTML created by GrapesJS for template design.

```
    <body id="iza8">
  <div class="gjs-row">
    <div class="gjs-cell">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ivq2" class="gjs-row">
    <div class="gjs-cell">
    </div>
    <div class="gjs-cell">
    </div>
    <div class="gjs-cell">
    </div>
  </div>
  <img id="ic4q" src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</body>
```

image src=" should be image URL instead of base64.

I am using below code for GrapeJs code

```
var editor = grapesjs.init({
   container: '#gjs',
    plugins: ['gjs-blocks-basic', 'grapesjs-plugin-forms'],
    pluginsOpts: {
    'grapesjs-plugin-forms': {/* Options */}
},
// Your configuration options
});
```

Comment: what is `instes"?